# Error using Keychain-Swift when running UI Tests on iOS 10 / XCode 8

Tags: swift, ios10, keychain, ui-testing

I'm using [keychain-swift](https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift) for storing my access credentials.
The library works fine when I run the app in the simulator for development, but if try to run UI Tests all the `keychain.get` and `keychain.delete` calls keep failing.

I followed the procedure reported on http://evgenii.com/blog/testing-a-keychain-library-in-xcode/ but it seems applicable to Unit Testing only. When I select the UI Tests target I see no "Allow testing Host Application APIs" as for the Unit test target. 
I need to reset the user session stored in the keychain after each test and I cannot figure it out how to proceed.

I placed a breakpoint in:

```
  @discardableResult
  open func clear() -> Bool {
    var query: [String: Any] = [ kSecClass as String : kSecClassGenericPassword ]
    query = addAccessGroupWhenPresent(query)
    query = addSynchronizableIfRequired(query, addingItems: false)
    lastQueryParameters = query

    lastResultCode = SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)

    return lastResultCode == noErr
  }
```

and the lastResultCode value when returning is -34018 (not sure if I'm prompting it correctly,thou)